# Does ReasonML support async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, reason, reasonml

I have been going through the [JS -> Reason cheatsheet on the Reason ML website](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/syntax-cheatsheet.html). They are very helpful, but none cover the `async`/`await` syntax available in modern ES.

What is the Reason ML equivalent of this?

```
import fs from 'mz/fs';

// A cat-like utility
const main = async () => {
  if (process.argv.length != 3) {
    throw new Error('Expected a file-path');
  }
  const path = process.argv[2];
  const content = await fs.readFile(path);
  console.log(content.toString());
};

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Probably [promises](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/promise.html#usage)?

Comment: There is a language extension called [bs-let](https://github.com/reasonml-labs/bs-let) that would allow you to do this.

Comment: It does not support Windows though, only Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ReasonML documentation](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/promise.html) says:

> Note: we might offer a dedicated syntax for JS promises (async/await) in the future.

Which means it doesn't currently support async/await.

Comment: What a shame! This makes Reason significantly less appealing than, say, F# + Fable.

Comment: Almost 3 years later you can still not use async-await with reasonml because BuckleScript does not yet support it. You can use bs-let as mentioned in a comment of the question but the repo warns that the generated code is not very performant.
I was looking for a type-safe way to write react code. Now Feliz, which is based on F# and Fable looks most promising (see https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Feliz).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently (October 2018) a ["Syntax proposal: async/await" Pull Request](https://github.com/facebook/reason/issues/1321) open to implement this that's been open for about 15 months now. At the end of last year one of the developers wrote a [blog post](https://jaredforsyth.com/posts/building-async-await-in-reason/) about their plans and noting some of the problems of handling some of the JavaScript Promise quirks. From the blog post there is even an example [Github repo](https://github.com/jaredly/reason_async) with support for async syntax that looks like this:

```
let getThing = () => Js.Promise.make((~resolve, ~reject) => [@bs]resolve(20));
let getOtherThing = () => Js.Promise.make((~resolve, ~reject) => [@bs]resolve(40));

let module Let_syntax = Reason_async.Promise;
let doSomething = () => {
  /* These two will be awaited concurrently (with Promise.all) */
  [%await let x = Js.Promise.resolve(10)
  and y = getThing()];

  [%awaitWrap let z = getOtherThing()];
  x + y + z + 3
};

/* Heyy look we have top-level await!
 * `consume` means "give me this promise, and have the result
 * of this whole expression be ()" */
{
  [%consume let result = doSomething()];
  Js.log(result)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like ReasonML but want async functionality, check out OCaml. 
[They have a few syntax differences](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/comparison-to-ocaml) but are otherwise very similar.
Reason even uses OCaml's compiler, and is basically OCaml with braces to make Javascript developers less afraid. OCaml has two async libraries in use: [Lwt](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt) and Jane Street's [Async](https://github.com/janestreet/async).